# ios How do I know the controller is a "push" or "pop" returned

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller, viewdidappear, popviewcontroller

i have three controller and i wanna kown the controller is a push or pop

A controller:

```
{
    if(!b)
     b = [B alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
}
```

B controller:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     //I want here to judge, from the "A" push over, or to return from the "C" "pop"

     //if it is push from A 
     //dosomething.....


     //if it is pop from C
     //dosomething
}
-(void)testAction:(id)sender
{
    C *c = [[C alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
    [c release];
}
```

C controller:

```
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand, please explain a little more

Comment: i had fix my question. can you got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** :

```
Add UINavigationControllerDelegate in .h file
```

Also do this:

```
[self.yournavController setDelegate:self];
```

Method below is `navigation controller delegate` which is called when the navigation controller `shows` a new `top view controller` via a `push`, `pop` or `setting` of the `view controller stack`.

Add this method

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{

}
```

Comment: i am sorry. when the controller which C pop to B that navigationController is not worked ,and i use A push B the function of navigationController not work too.why?

Comment: thanks ,i fix it .i have a baseController ,i use self.navigationController.delegate = self; in viewDidLoad it was worked when A push B ,but is is not work when C pop B.---i take -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{self.navigationController.delegate = self;} it is worked.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the UIViewController method, isMovingToParentViewController. This will return YES if the view controller is being shown because it was pushed, but NO if it is shown because another view controller was popped off the stack.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { //Code in view controller B
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"isMovingToParentViewController: %d",self.isMovingToParentViewController);
    // this will log 1 if pushing from A but 0 if C is popped
}
```

Comment: @zt9788, I've tested this, and it does work. Did you put the method in the viewDidAppear:animated: method?  That's where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think for that you need to track a global variable that knows either it is push from A or pop from C. What I would do is:

1. Declare a `BOOL` variable `isPush` in appDelegate or some external .h file and synthesize it.
2. When you are going from A to B i.e. it is a push, make it equal "YES" in A.

```cs
yourAppDelegate *myDelegate = (yourAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication SharedApplication] delegate];

myDelegate.isPush = YES;
```

Similarly before popping from C, make value of `isPush = NO`;

1. In B's `viewDidLoad`, see the value of variable.

```cs
yourAppDelegate *myDelegate = (yourAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication SharedApplication] delegate];

if(myDelegate.isPush)
//means A was pushed

else
//means C was popped
```